# Should I always removeEventListener?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

Say I add a `load` event to the window like so:

```
window.addEventListener("load",initialize);
```

Should I then remove the load event listener from the window after the event is fired? It only fires once, but will it continue to listen after that happens?

It's simple enough to do:

```
function initialize(event_){
    /* Just by adding this line. */
    window.removeEventListener("load",initialize);
}
```

But is that overkill or will that actually benefit the performance of my program? I only ask because the "load" event only fires once, so it would make sense if it just resolved itself. I've never heard of a self resolving listener, though... Any thoughts?

Edit: Also, I'm not concerned specifically with the "load" event, just the general scenario where the listener continues to listen for an event that only fires once.

Comment: If you're unsure about this method, why not try `window.onload=initialize;`  This will call your initialize function but won't continue as an eventlistener. I can't see any reason for removing the load event listener but i'm just giving another option/method but both will do the same thing.

Comment: There's no reason to do that. (@NewToJS ?? setting the `onload` property of `window` is just another way of establishing an event handler.)

Comment: @Pointy I understand that, i'm just sharing another method of triggering it but as you clearly pointed out, there isn't any reason for removing the event.

Comment: I'm not so concerned with the actual load event, just the specific scenario of removing the listener and whether or not a listener will continue listening for an event that only fires once after the fact.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Should I then remove the load event listener from the window after the event is fired?

I've never seen that done, so I don't think there's a real need for it.

> It only fires once, but will it continue to listen after that happens?

It is only fired once by the DOM, yes. But it will continue to listen, you could easily trigger a `load` event manually (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) for examples).

> But is that overkill or will that actually benefit the performance of my program?

Typically it's overkill, as this doesn't make a huge difference. Of course, it might trigger garbage collection on `initialize`, which could save a bit of memory (or more, depending on your code structure) and improve performance by making it available to the rest of your app.

Comment: Also I think people are thrown off when they hear the term "listen", as no one is actually "listening" (in the active sense) for anything. When you register an event handler, all you do is append a function to an array (behind the scenes). When an event triggers, it just checks out that array and calls each function there, so this is a huge gain compared to looping and checking to see whether something happened or not. So removing handlers from there is just making the size of that list smaller. This does free up some memory, but, like you said, it's a bit of over engineering.

Answer (score 21):

`window.addEventListener('load', initialize, {once: true});`

Comment: could you include some explanation about the answer?

Comment: There is a good write up on the topic ( particularly last example ) https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/addeventlistener-once

Comment: I have since discovered this new functionality and use it all the time. `{ once:true }` simply tells the event listener to detect only one event and then remove itself.

Comment: Here it is in 2020 and TIL about `once`